# Htaccess rewrite GET request to another GET request and another with 2 GET variables

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have two url's I'm trying to rewrite, for the past... 4-5 hours (headache now).

I am trying to rewrite

```
/arts/tag/?tag=keyword
```

to

```
/search/art?keywords=keyword
```

Looking at other questions I formulated my rewrite like this

```
RewriteRule /arts/tag/?tag=([^&]+) search/art?keywords=$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^arts/tag/?tag=$ /search/art\?keywords=%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

I tried with backslashes and without, no luck.

Also tried

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} /arts/tag/?tag=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /search/art\?keywords=%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

---

The second one is similar,

```
/arts/category?id=1&sortby=views&featured=1
```

to

```
/art/moved?id=1&rearrange=view
```

The reason I change the get variable name is for my own learning purpose as I haven't found any tutorials for my purpose. I also changed category to moved since the categories have changed and I have to internally redirect some ID #'s.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+) [NC] // I need the path in there though, not just query string, since I'll be redirecting /blogs/category and /art/category to different places.
RewriteRule .* /art/moved/id=%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you append to a query string, you should use `QSA` as a flag to your `RewriteRule` (QSA stands for "Query String Append").

Comment: Like so ? RewriteRule /arts/tag/?tag=$ /search/art?keywords=$1 [QSA,NC] , still nothing. I tried implementing QSA in all the codes posted above, not just that one.

Comment: Describe the problem please. There is no substitution, there are errors, both, ¿what?

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA There are no errors, but none of the rewrites work for me. I need /arts/tag/?tag=keyword  to rewrite to /search/art?keywords=keyword but none of the rewrites I wrote, work. No errors.

Comment: I see the queries to be replaced have almost nothing in common with the substitution queries. ¿Is there anything to be copied from one to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the queries in the original URLs have nothing in common with those in the substitution URLs, maybe this will do what you want, using the first `key`in the query as a condition and to identify the incoming URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# First case
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  \btag\b
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/search/art?keywords=keyword?  [L]
```

Will map this:
`http://example.com/arts/tag/?tag=keyword`

To this:
`http://example.com/search/art?keywords=keyword`

```
# Second case
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  \bid\b
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/art/moved?id=1&rearrange=view?  [L]
```

Will map this:
`http://example.com/arts/category?id=1&sortby=views&featured=1`

To this:
`http://example.com/art/moved?id=1&rearrange=view`

Both are mapped silently. If the new URL is to be shown in the browser's address bar modify the flags like this `[R,L]`. Replace `R` with `R=301` for a permanent redirect.

Comment: Thank you for this. For first one, if I'm specifically rewriting for /arts and want to don't want /videos to rewrite, how would I state that? and if keyword is dynamic, would I use $1 or %1, "keyword" is dynamic. So to restate, I only want to rewrite when in /arts and not for /videos or /blog  under same conditions.

Same for 2nd case.

Thank you. This worked, just need to see how it can be dynamic.

Comment: So you want the first `key`to be dynamic and only `/arts` and `/category` in the respective URLs, anything else should be rejected. ¿Am I right? Will wait for your comment to update my answer.

Comment: I want /VIDEOS/tag/?tag=keyword to remain untouched, but if it's /ARTS/tag/?tag=keyword to process rewrite. Also, the word "keyword" is dynamic, so in rewrite, if url was /arts/tag/?tag=hello it should rewrite to search/art?keywords=hello the keywords is dynamic variable. For 2nd query, same thing, the GET variables should be dynamic in rewrite. Thank you very much for your help. You are the greatest!

Comment: @Darius You say `http://videos/tag/?tag=keyword` to remain untouched and `http://arts/tag/?tag=keyword` to process rewrite. My interpretation is: All URLs like `http://anything/tag/?tag=keyword` should be mapped, except when `/anything` is `/videos`. On the other hand, the parameters in the example `http://arts/tag/?tag=hello` have no correlation with those in `http://search/art?keywords=hello`. Try using `keyN` for the parameter name and `valN` for the parameter value to denote they are variables. For example: `http://arts/key1/?key1=val1` to `http://search/key1?key1=val1`.

Comment: That way, when `keyN` or `valN` are not used, it means it is a fixed string like `search`. Please modify my example accordingly.

Comment: You are correct, I only wish to map http://arts/tag/?tag=val1 to http://search/art?keywords=val1 . URLS like http://ANYTHING/tag/?tag=val1 should not be mapped. There are no correlations, but I explicitly wish to state that arts/tag/?tag=val1 be redirected to search/art?keywords=val1 , meaning only when directory is /arts/. I will try tonight to do what you explained with KeyN. If you like hinting me in the right direction after this explanation, would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I think is clear. About the exception, you want the opposite of my interpretation. That is: No URL is mapped, except when `/anything` is `/arts`. About the examples `arts`, `art`, `tag`, `search` and `keywords` are fixed strings and the only variable is `val1`. ¿Am I right? Take your time and think it over if not, there is no hurry.